# Converting a database result of 3 columns to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a MySQL query that returns the following result:

```
+----------+----------+-------+
| ApptTime | ApptType | Count |
+----------+----------+-------+
| 16:00    | pickup   | 1     |
+----------+----------+-------+
| 16:30    | dropoff  | 1     |
+----------+----------+-------+
| 16:30    | pickup   | 6     |
+----------+----------+-------+
| 16:45    | pickup   | 2     |
+----------+----------+-------+
| 16:45    | dropoff  | 1     |
+----------+----------+-------+
```

I need to loop through the result and create a new associative array where the key is the `ApptTime` and the value is the combination of `ApptType` and `Count` like so:

```
"16:00" => "1 pickup"
"16:30" => "1 dropoff, 6 pickup" //the order in which appointments are listed is irrelevant. 
"16:45" => "1 dropoff, 2 pickup"
```

I've tried looping through the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` result in a variety of ways and creating a new array within the loop but I'm fundamentally not understanding how to go about it so it's not working out.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You wouldn't "loop thru" fetch assoc.  That fnc will return each row as an associative array.  A list of assoc's.

Comment: Post your php, you'll get a better answer.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to mysqli. It would be nice if you could post [MCVE] build using `var_export()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using two loops. One to prepare the values for the format you want, and one to actually put the values in that format.

First, prepare the data

```
$array = array(
    array('ApptTime' => "16:00", 'ApptType' => "pickup", 'Count' => 1),
    array('ApptTime' => "16:30", 'ApptType' => "dropoff", 'Count' => 1),
    array('ApptTime' => "16:30", 'ApptType' => "pickup", 'Count' => 6),
    array('ApptTime' => "16:45", 'ApptType' => "pickup", 'Count' => 2),
    array('ApptTime' => "16:45", 'ApptType' => "dropoff", 'Count' => 1)
);

$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $arr) {

    $time = $arr['ApptTime'];
    $type = $arr['ApptType'];
    $count = $arr['Count'];

    //check if `$time` exists as key of `$new_array`, if not, create it with an empty array value
    if(!array_key_exists($time, $new_array)) {
        $new_array[$time] = [];
    }

    //add string e.g "1 pickup" as array value to array `$new_array` with key `$time`
    $new_array[$time][] = "{$count} {$type}";
}
```

First loop return

```
Array
(
    [16:00] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 pickup
        )

    [16:30] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1 dropoff
            [1] => 6 pickup
        )

    [16:45] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2 pickup
            [1] => 1 dropoff
        )

)
```

And this is where I would personally stop, and format the values when actually needed to be displayed. However, the following loop can be used to modify the `$new_array` to the format you wanted.

```
foreach($new_array as &$n_arr) {
    $n_arr = implode(', ', $n_arr);
}
```

Second loop return

```
Array
(
    [16:00] => 1 pickup
    [16:30] => 1 dropoff, 6 pickup
    [16:45] => 2 pickup, 1 dropoff
)
```

Comment: Same thing i did only missing second looping. Upvoting you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know of `array_key_exists` and `implode`. By the way, there is an extra closing square brace at $new_array[$time]][] in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this logic :

I have taken sample array assuming you are getting same in MySql resultset.

```php
<?php

$resultset = array(
     array("16:00","pickup", 1),
     array("16:30","Drop of ", 1),
     array("16:30","pickup", 6),
     array("16:45","pickup", 2),
     array("16:45","Drop of ", 1)

    );
    $sample_array=array();
    foreach ( $resultset as $value )
   {
       //var_dump($value);
       if(!array_key_exists($value[0],$sample_array)){

           $sample_array[$value[0]] = array();
       }
       array_push($sample_array[$value[0]],$value[2]." ".$value[1]);
       //var_dump($sample_array);

   } 
   var_dump($sample_array);
?>
```

Output :

```
array(3) {
  ["16:00"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "1 pickup"
  }
  ["16:30"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "1 Drop of "
    [1]=>
    string(8) "6 pickup"
  }
  ["16:45"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "2 pickup"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "1 Drop of "
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't match OPs output.

Comment: added expected one. Logic can used only need to merge in string. Why downvote ?

Comment: Because your solution does not match OPs expected output.

Comment: see update answer its match associated array as per expected output.